# What is the canonical mechanism for creating a Ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I've looked in a lot of places - including www.rubygems.org - but can't find any tutorial that describes an easy, straightforward, technique for producing gems that doesn't rely on other (non-standard-Ruby) components, such as newgem and hoe.

I have several requirements for gem production, from the simplest case of one library file+one test file, to complex ones involving C source files and multiple utility .rb files.

All help gratefully received!

Comment: You've looked at the other questions tagged "rubygems" that ask about how to create a ruby gem, right?

Answer (score 4):

I was researching gem making recently and was also surprised that there wasn't a single, obvious way that everyone does it like how RubyGems is the one-stop shop for managing gems. I discovered that you can actually use Bundler to create gems, and I've chosen this route for my own gems. Take a look at this [guide on gem development with Bundler](https://github.com/radar/guides/blob/master/gem-development.md) by Radar.

Comment: oh, thats has really cool potential. I need to look into it. Bundler is a great tool, and with that addition, it might be the way to go. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: also +1 for the link to radar's guides. what a cool idea love the OS book concept, now a watcher of the project.

Answer (score 2):

look into Jeweler or one of these options:
http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/gem_creation.html

its seems like overkill, but you don't need to use all the options, you can use it just to create the skeleton of the gem.

Comment: First, thanks for the answer: I will check into all those things listed there. But what I really want to know is: is there a decent tutorial for building gems using only the basic gem library?

Comment: I went through this a couple months ago, you can see my related stackoverflow questions regarding gem building. What I found is that its much easier to use one of the automated scaffolding gem libs above to get the majority setup and go from there. the basic rubygem build commands work as long as there is a gemspec file, but the tools like jeweler let you get the basics covered right away.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently been looking into the same thing. Here are a few sources I found useful [Walk through of a simple gem](http://www.5dollarwhitebox.org/drupal/creating_a_rubygem_package), [Gem spec reference](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/20#page85). Also I found it useful to check out large projects on github and model after them [Thor's Gem spec](https://github.com/wycats/thor/blob/master/thor.gemspec).

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you've seen "[Gemcutter Is The New Official Default RubyGem Host](http://www.rubyinside.com/gemcutter-is-the-new-official-default-rubygem-host-2659.html)", but it's a good starting point. [RubyGems.org](http://rubygems.org/) is a good second stop to read [Creating Your Own Gem](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/5).